# How to fix the following error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql, .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying use a API in C# with database MySQL in the same container for don't necessary install dependencies of the API or of the database. But i'm with follow error: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

The dockerfile that build for API and database:

```
# Database
FROM mysql:8.0

# ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bd1374
# ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD: bd1374
# ENV MYSQL_DATABASE: scage

COPY ./create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# User scage API
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["scage-users-api/SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.api/SCAGEUsers.api.csproj", "SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.api/"]
COPY ["scage-users-api/SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.Application/SCAGEUsers.Application.csproj", "SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.Application/"]
COPY ["scage-users-api/SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.Infrastructure/SCAGEUsers.Infrastructure.csproj", "SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.api/SCAGEUsers.api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/scage-users-api/SCAGEUsers/SCAGEUsers.api"
RUN dotnet build "SCAGEUsers.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SCAGEUsers.api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SCAGEUsers.api.dll"]
```

The docker-compose file is the following:

```
version: '1.0'

services:
  api:    
    image: scage-user-image
    container_name: scage-user-container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - "5122:80"
    restart: always
  
  database: 
    image: mysql
    container_name: scage-database-container
    # build: 
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:  
      # MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bd1374
      # # MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: bd1374
      MYSQL_DATABASE: scage

volumes:
  db-volume:
```

In the enviroment variables of the API is the following:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=scage;Uid=root;Pwd=bd1374"
    // "DefaultConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=scage;Uid=root;Pwd=root"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker almost always refers to the current container. See for example [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for details about connecting to other containers.

Comment: (Your Compose file isn't actually a version 1 Compose file, and `version: '3.8'` might be more correct.  The `mysql` part of your Dockerfile isn't used at all.  `expose:` doesn't do anything and you can delete it; you also don't normally need to manually set `container_name:`.)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a compose file like this:

```
services:
  client:
    image: docker-mysql
    container_name: client
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always
  
  database: 
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test123

volumes:
  db-volume:
```

The .NET code in `Program.cs` might be something like this:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DockerMySQL {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string connectionString = "server=database;user=root;password=test123;database=mysql";

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            try {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                    connection.Open();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to MySQL!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `server` specified in the connection string should be the same as the name of the service specified in `docker-compose.yml`. Just using the default `mysql` database, but you can create another one.

You need a `Dockerfile` to build and publish the client application too.

```
# Stage 1: Build application.
#
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY docker-mysql /app
RUN dotnet restore docker-mysql.csproj
RUN dotnet build docker-mysql.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish docker-mysql.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

# Stage 2: Create runtime image.
#
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:latest AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "docker-mysql.dll"]
```

More details can be found [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/net-and-mysql-in-docker/).